# Impossible to see data in DataGridView until i click or select cells C#

Tags: c#, database, windows, winforms

Seems like the font of text in DataGridView is similliar to background color, so i can't see any data until i click or select cells. I tried to change colors in `DefaultCellStyle` but nothing happened. How can i fix it?

Here is my `DefaultCellStyle` code:

```
dataGridViewCellStyle1.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
dataGridViewCellStyle1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(204)));
dataGridViewCellStyle1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
dataGridViewCellStyle1.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
dataGridViewCellStyle1.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText;
```

**It's should be okay like on this preview:**

[image]

**But it's not:**

[image]

Comment: Forecolor is transparent which affects text color

Comment: @AleksaRistic changed it to Red and I still have this issue. It looks good only in CellStyle Builder preview

Comment: When you change it from that window, check if changes applied inside code

Comment: @AleksaRistic yes it is, but when i compile my program and run it, it changes to Transparent back, but not inside the designer code, just in properties. It is so strange...

Comment: alright i just programmaticaly changed it in my form.cs

Comment: Glad i helped :)

Comment: @Aleksa Ristic thanks ;)

Comment: This usually happens in Visual Studio too, when the Parent Form's `Forecolor` is the same as the `DataGrdiView.BackColor`. Many controls inherit this property from the Parent. Changing the general `DefaultCellStyle` or setting the Form's ForeColor to something else usually corrects it.

Comment: Or set the `RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor` to the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is a bug in SharpDevelop. I'm not sure, but my friend hasnt got any problems with this in Visual Studio. To fix this problem, simply add this row to your `Form.cs` (not to your designer).

```
dataGridView.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was because of trying to update the DGV from another thread ,
using invoke worked for me.

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
 {
//update DGV 
  }));
```